# MySQL variable as result of subquery with elements of other table

Tags: mysql

I have a working query:

```sql
SELECT count(*),
       AVG(
             (SELECT sum(order_fills.quant * order_fills.price)
              FROM order_fills
              WHERE `type`='closed'
                AND order_fills.transaction_id = transactions.id) -
             (SELECT sum(order_fills.quant * order_fills.price)
              FROM order_fills
              WHERE `type`='opened'
                AND order_fills.transaction_id = transactions.id)) AS avgProfit,
       SUM(
             (SELECT sum(order_fills.quant * order_fills.price)
              FROM order_fills
              WHERE `type`='closed'
                AND order_fills.transaction_id = transactions.id)) AS volume,
FROM transactions
WHERE transactions.status='closed';
```

to make the code more readable I wish to set some parts of that query into variables.

I wish to achieve something like that (it does not work, returns `null`):

```
SET @transSells =
          (SELECT sum(order_fills.quant * order_fills.price)
           FROM order_fills
           WHERE type='closed'
             AND order_fills.transaction_id = transactions.id);


SET @transBuys =
          (SELECT sum(order_fills.quant * order_fills.price)
           FROM order_fills
           WHERE type='opened'
             AND order_fills.transaction_id = transactions.id);


SELECT avg(@transSells - @transBuys) AS `avgProfit`,
       sum(@transSells + @transBuys) AS `volume`
FROM transactions WHERE transactions.status='closed'
```

I think the problem might be that part of subquery `WHERE` statement is the result of the main query and another table (`transactions.id`):

`AND order_fills.transaction_id = transactions.id`

Answer (score 1):

The reason your variable query doesn't work is that `transactions.id` in the `WHERE` clause of your variable definitions is not defined (`NULL`), hence the queries won't return any results.

I think you can simplify your query by putting the variables into a derived table using conditional aggregation that you then `JOIN` to:

```
SELECT AVG(transSells - transBuys) AS avgProfit,
       SUM(transSells + transBuys) AS volume
FROM transactions
JOIN (SELECT transaction_id,
             SUM(CASE WHEN type='closed' THEN quant * price ELSE 0 END) AS transSells,
             SUM(CASE WHEN type='opened' THEN quant * price ELSE 0 END) AS transBuys
      FROM order_fills) o ON o.transaction_id = transactions.id
WHERE status = 'closed'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a slightly better solution for my case:

setting variables inside the query, and then using them in the same, single query.

```
 SET @comission = 0.03;

    SELECT count(*),
           AVG(
                 ( @transSells := (SELECT sum(order_fills.quant * order_fills.price)
                  FROM order_fills
                  WHERE `type`='closed'
                    AND order_fills.transaction_id = transactions.id)) 
                  -
                 ( @transBuys := (SELECT sum(order_fills.quant * order_fills.price)
                  FROM order_fills
                  WHERE `type`='opened'
                    AND order_fills.transaction_id = transactions.id))) AS avgProfit,

           SUM( @transSells ) AS volume,

           SUM( @transSells * @comission )

    FROM transactions
    WHERE transactions.status='closed';
```

Comment: While this might work when you test it, it's a bit risky, see [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html): a) *The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined. For example, there is no guarantee that SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1 evaluates @a first and then performs the assignment.* b) *This functionality is supported in MySQL 8.0 for backward compatibility but is subject to removal in a future release of MySQL.* In general, if there's a way without using variables (there isn't always), you should use it.